# Is it possible to static the dynamic url of sharepoint hosted app in sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

The default sharepoint hosted app url looks like 
http://[app prefix]-[app id].[domain name]/[site collection path]/[app path]/pages/default.aspx. It is pathetic because every deployment during QA/UAT generates new url. We have to ask our tester/clients to perform testing/UAT on new url.
Is there anyway to static the app url?

Answer (score 0):

Static URL is available only for Provider Hosted Apps.

The workaround you can do is create a page and put a redirect in that page to your app. This way you can share the page URL to the end user.

After each deployment you should change the redirect url in the page.

Comment: Thanks for reply, however I have to pass the query string parameters containing the real time values with the site page url to which we want to redirect..

Comment: have your redirect page extract the querystring parameters and generate a ``document.location=`` call

Comment: If the page url's are dynamic then this approach will not work. Because you are providing end users a static URL.